# Get Blogger post after button click

Tags: jquery, blogger

I'm using the Blogger API, it's my first time using an API and REST, and I got stuck here...

Instead of doing it this way (from Blogger API's docs):

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  function handleResponse(response) {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<h1>" + response.title + "</h1>" + response.content;
  }
</script>
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3213900/posts/8398240586497962757?callback=handleResponse&key=YOUR-API-KEY"></script>
```

... I want to make the call after a button click (since the page will load more elements and blogger's post is optional).

In other words, I want to get the response and be able to work with it after the user clicks the button, instead of getting it when that script loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to the API:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3213900/posts/8398240586497962757?key=YOUR-API-KEY",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            // work with returned data
        },
        error: function(data, status, xhr) {
            // do stuff with error
        }
    });
});
```

The data type can of course be altered depending on what you are expecting back from the server.

Comment: Perfect and simple, thank you very much! Those docs need more help for beginners, it seems...

Comment: @Kirby Agreed, although you'll get used to it :)

Answer (score 0):

call your function when the user clicks on button.

```
<button onclick="handleResponse()">Response</button>
```

Comment: But wouldn't this make the call (using the <script src=...), before I click the button (which is what I'm trying to prevent)?